# Cannot write configuration file while New-SPWebApplication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, 2019, iis7

When I use New-SPWebApplication I am getting error below error in SharePoint 2019

[image]

I am using SharePoint Farm Admin account. What can be the reason for it. Some time It will finsih without error

Comment: Now it is not working at all. Any help appriciated

Comment: If it works sometimes and sometimes not, i would suspect AntiVirus-Software installed on your SharePoint Servers.

Comment: I don't have antivirus installed. I have tried with CA it created successfully but what I found that it did not created on one of my Application Server. So I make in IIS manually with same configuration as other Application Server. But now new issue rises wsp don't install on all server and when I do Test-SPContentDatabase it always tells that wsp is not installed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the C:\Drive has enough space and make sure application pool account has the proper Share permissions on the shared folder.

Besides, you can try to create web application from CA.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3d275163-5d5c-4bff-90b2-5f029fa2c76a/cannot-write-configuration-file-while-newspwebapplication?forum=SP2019

https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB43281-Error-quot-Cannot-write-configuration-file-quot-appears?language=en_US

https://jwcooney.com/2014/05/22/iis-cannot-write-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions/

Comment: C:\ has more than 100 GB space. 

Next I though some process is stopping to write in config file so I tried to run PSCONFIG GUI that also gives me same error.

Yes I tried with CA that too gives me same error.

Comment: It don't have any permission issue also I have checked that too

Comment: Can you create web application from CA?

Comment: Yes, I can make New Web Application successfully

Comment: I need help from professional. I found something so I want to know will it be correct to do so. 

I disable two services

AppFabric event Collection Service
AppFabric WorkFlow Management Service
Which resolve the issue. I want to know is it correct resolution and why it is doing like that

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the SharePoint Management Shell elevated?

You need local admin privileges to write to that file from the shell (as you’re not going through the timer service here).

Comment: I need help from professional. I found something so I want to know will it be correct to do so. 

I disable two services

AppFabric event Collection Service
AppFabric WorkFlow Management Service
Which resolve the issue. I want to know is it correct resolution and why it is doing like that